# Word for increasing acceleration

Tags: single-word-requests

When you increase your distance you go farther.
When you increase your speed you go faster.
When you increase your acceleration you go ______?
I just can't think of the word to describe the increase of acceleration, I almost thought accelerate but that's the same as go faster.

Comment: When you increase your acceleration you go faster, faster? Is there a particular context you need this for? I don't think you'll find a word for this since the concept is a pretty modern scientific one; it's not something that we particularly detect or care about as humans.

Comment: That's kind of what I was worried about. As for context, I'll be using it on a button for a game, but I limited space and increase acceleration doesn't quite fit.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because it does not quite fit the question exactly as it's phrased but I would suggest naming the button [accelerate](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=accelerate&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) as in  "When you increase your acceleration, you accelerate." If that doesn't fit, I'd abbreviate it to "Accel." in order to save space and what is meant should be fairly clear.

Comment: Tonepoet, to accelerate is to increase velocity, not acceleration, it even says that in the link you have.

Comment: Hmm... *wavier*? *more time dilated?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term in physics for the rate of change in acceleration appears to be "**jerk**", "**jolt**", "**lurch**", or "**surge**".

So maybe the comparative form is "**jerkier**"?

I would probably just say you "go faster faster".

See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)).

Comment: Jerk is (somewhat surprisingly) the technical term for the derivative of acceleration (i.e. if jerk is positive your acceleration is increasing.)

Comment: @DRF If I have to be exposed to a jerk, I guess I prefer a _positive_ jerk.

Comment: It may not quite be what the OP wants.  "Increase the acceleration until the pilot is pressed firmly into the seat back" ... not the same as:  "Jerk until the pilot is pressed firmly into the seat back."  Maybe *surge* would work here.

Comment: If you told me something was getting jerkier, I'd probably think of increasingly abrupt and unpredictable changes in pace or direction, like a jalopy trying to go uphill while running out of gas or a wavering hand at the onset of a nervous breakdown, more than anything else. That is because the intermediary form is [jerky](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=jerky&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on). Pressing a button to make the plane jerkier sounds dangerous for that reason, in fact..

Comment: Thanks, I think I am going to go with "go faster, faster".

Answer (score 1):

In a long career in physics I have never met a general word that describes an increasing acceleration in the same way that acceleration describes an increasing velocity.

Comment: In a fairly long career in teaching maths, I'd never met a term used to describe the rate of change of acceleration wrt time. But I have now, thanks to Dog Lover and Wikipedia.

Comment: Back in summer class at Centre College in, I think, 1965, I was told that the term is "jerk".

Comment: The trouble with jerk and similar words is that, although correctly associated with a sudden increase in acceleration (which occurs with a sudden increase in applied force) they describe a phenomenon of limited duration only. They do not describe the general concept of an increasing acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

"Thrust" as in to apply more thrust.

Comment: That isn't even necessarily acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

You go at an *increased rate of acceleration*.